# Sitecore scheduled publishing with Publishing service

Tags: publishing, publishing-service

With Sitecore Publishing Service installed, is it possible to have scheduled publishes. How can do add our custom schedule to the Publishing queue of Publishing Instance.

Comment: You can use the default Sitecore Publishing agent (`Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent`). It will use the Publishing service.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the default Sitecore Publishing Agent. It is found in the `Sitecore.config`. You can search for it by using `Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent`.

You just need to configure the source and target database (default: master and web). I had asked the same question to Sitecore Support and their response was that the methods from the Sitecore.Publishing.PublishManager class to perform new publishing.

For an example:

```
PublishManager.PublishSmart(database, targets, languageArray);
PublishManager.PublishIncremental(database, targets, languageArray);
```

In Sitecore 8.2 Update -2 default PublishAgent works fine and calls the new Publish Module.

Comment: Is it possible to have a similar agent on the publishing service "application"? I mean, I want to be sure that the publishing service publishes even if the content manager is down.

Comment: Yes it is possible but you’ll need to write custom code. I would suggest to use hangfire